# How to create a Macro that only applies a formula to filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro that can be reused with reports containing different data (but same formatting / template). I want to filter a column (col K) with only values that contain "Y" and then add a simple formula (=value in same row in col N) in another column (col I).
This is the macro I have created:
It works but my row 11 always has the formula added, even if it should not because it does not have value Y in col K.

```vb
`Sub clean()
'
' clean Macro

    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$4222").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("I11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[5]"
    Range("I11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J11").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("I1048576").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range("I11:I1048576").Select
    Range("I1048576").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I1048575").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Y").AutoFilter Field:=11
End Sub
```

I want a macro that can be used with different values / data. Something that is not specific to a` particular row number.

Comment: Why don't you use a formula in column I: `=IF(K2="Y",N2,"")`?

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Ike would be the way to go, but if you want a VBA solution and the formula in just the filtered rows....

```
Public Sub Clean()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        'Get the last row number based on data in column A (col 1).
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Set reference from range A1 (1, 1)  to last row in column S (LastRow, 19).
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 19))
    End With
    
    With DataRange
    
        'Turn the AutoFilter off if it's turned on.
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            .Parent.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
        End If
    
        'Apply a new filter.
        .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=Y"
        
        'Add the formula to the visible cells in column 9 of the DataRange.
        'Note: Column 9 will not be column I if DataRange doesn't start in column A.
        .Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[5]"
        
        'Remove the filter.
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            .Parent.ShowAllData
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Further reading:
[With...End With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)